# How do I configure a http inbound channel adapter with JAVA config in Spring Integration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-http

I found a xml configured inbound adapter example what I do not fully understand. The configuration  specifies a REST request setting request method, consumed format, etc.

I thought from the Spring Integration point of view the response should be much more important because the response is what is acutally feeding the message channel. Am I right?

The HTTP inbound adapter is used as message endpoint (actually a message startpoint) which calls a HTTP request - the URL of a REST service, let's say "http://myRest/transfer/next" - feeding a SI message channel with its result. Is that right?

It is either hard to find an example or to transform other examples into something which covers my needs. Even more as many examples are XML configured whereas I want to configure with Java or Dsl.

I am looking for an example where a REST service (which I will provide) is called which returns a JSON representation of `TransferRequest` object of mine which is fed into the SI channel "transfer_next_channel" to get processed by the Message Handler.

My code approach is rather skeleton-like. What do I have to do?

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow httpInboundFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Http.inboundChannelAdapter("http://myRest/transfer/next")
                    .requestMapping(r -> r
                            .methods(HttpMethod.GET)
                            .consumes("text/html"))
                    .requestPayloadType(TransferRequest.class)
                    .headerMapper(myHeaderMapper)
                    )
            .channel("transfer_next_channel")
            .get();
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "transfer_next_channel")
public MessageHandler handler() {
    return new MessageHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
            System.out.println("myHandler: " + message.getPayload());
            System.out.println("myHandler: " + message.getHeaders());
        }
    };
}
```

**EDIT 1**

The whole thing is to generate a data message of a person from persistent DB state to a String message via TCP/IP. At first there is the information what message is needed. It is provided via external REST service. The result is a `TransferRequest` entity. From this the message has to be generated: another external REST service call to transform `TransferRequest` into some kind of `DataMessage`, the required data message. That result will be delivered via TCP/IP server as soon as a TCP/IP client has connected.

**EDIT 2**

The message channel is: starts with a request "http://myRest/transfer/next" to an external service, gets `TransferRequest`(containing a `personId`), push it as message into the channel, transformer/handler to request (another) external service "http://myRest/message/{personId}", gets `DataMessage`, push it as message into another channel, handler to push the message into a TcpOutboundGateway to be received by an external system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably there is some misunderstanding in terminology:

1. The Inbound Channel Adapter is an entry point for your application. We can call it `server`, which is expecting external requests and you do some logic downstream. With an `Http.inboundChannelAdapter` we talk about a Spring MVC controller.
2. Unlike an Inbound Gateway, the Inbound Channel Adapter is a one-way entry point. So no reply (response) is expected for the external caller - the REST service.
3. Another misunderstanding probably comes with misleading property names. Although they still are valid. The `requestPayloadType` is what makes conversion for the HTTP request body in that Inbound Channel Adapter and this data is going to be packed into the payload of the message to be sent to that `transfer_next_channel`.

You probably need to think of replacing your `@ServiceActivator` with a `handle()` like this:

```
 .channel("transfer_next_channel")
 .<TransferRequest>handle((p, h) -> )
 .get();
```

Note: you may not need that channel in between, the `IntegrationFlow` will take care of that for you.

Probably you to dig Spring Integration Reference Manual more to understand concepts of channel adapters, gateways and DSL.

Comment: What scenario would you propose? I added **EDIT 1** to the question..
The end part made me think to use SI to benefit from its TCP/IP opportunities. So I thought I'll use a Http Inbound Adapter to request the REST service to feed the channel, do another REST request on the way to the TCP/IP endpoint. Now I understood the entry point has to be an Inbound Gateway, requesting the `TransferRequest` entity.

Comment: Still not clear from your description if you call some external REST service (being HTTP client) or you are the server for that exposed REST service. Let's assume the latest since you don't have the whole `http://` in your mapping, so what you need is a `transform()` to create that `DataMessage` for TCP call and then use a `handle(Tcp.outboundGateway())`

Comment: Thanks, Artem! Sorry, it is the first. So the mapping should have been `Http.httpInboundAnything("http://myRest/transfer/next")` since an external REST service is to be called to get the next person for whom to send a `DataMessage`. What does it change then?

Comment: It change it radically. You need then an `Http.outboundGateway()`. This is what we call `REST client`. The "outbound" means that we are going to call, not us. See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/http.html#http-outbound

Comment: Thanks a lot, Artem! So you were right: Probably there is some misunderstanding in terminology. ... And I am at the very start again.

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
 @Bean
public IntegrationFlow httpInboundFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Http.inboundGateway("/demo")
                    .replyChannel("reply")
                    .requestMapping(r -> r.methods(HttpMethod.GET))
                    .requestPayloadType(String.class)
            )
            .channel("next")
            .get();
}


@Bean
public MessageChannel reply() {
    return new QueueChannel();
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "next",outputChannel = "reply")
public Function<Message<?>, String> handler() {
    return new Function<Message<?>, String>() {
        public String apply(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
            System.out.println("myHandler: " + message.getPayload());
            System.out.println("myHandler: " + message.getHeaders());
            return "ok";
        }

    };

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Can you explain shortly, why Inbound Gateway instead of Inbound Adapter?

Comment: See my answer. See some short explanation of the difference in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/endpoint-summary.html#endpoint-summary